# Can I serve JSPs from inside a JAR in lib, or is there a workaround?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, tiles

I have a web application deployed as a WAR file in Tomcat 7. The application is build as a multi-module project:

- core - packaged as JAR, contains most of the backend code
- core-api - packaged as JAR, contains interfaces toward core
- webapp - packaged as WAR, contains frontend code and depends on core
- customer-extensions - optional module, packaged as JAR

Normally, we can put our JSP files in the webapp project, and reference them relative to the context:

```
/WEB-INF/jsp/someMagicalPage.jsp
```

The question is what we do about JSP files that are specific to the customer-extensions project, that should not always be included in the WAR. Unfortunately, I cannot refer to JSPs inside JAR files, it appears. Attempting `classpath:jsp/customerMagicalPage.jsp` results in a file not found in the JspServlet, since it uses `ServletContext.getResource()`.

Traditionally, we "solved" this having maven unpack the customer-extensions JAR, locate the JSPs, and put them in the WAR when building it. But an ideal situation is where you just drop a JAR in the exploded WAR in Tomcat and the extension is discovered - which works for everything but the JSPs.

Is there anyway to solve this? A standard way, a Tomcat-specific way, a hack, or a workaround? For example, I've been thinking of unpacking the JSPs on application startup...

Comment: war should contain jsp,js and servlets.

Comment: related: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=58441

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Servlet 3.0 which Tomcat 7 supports includes the ability to package jsps into a jar.

You need to:

- place your jsps in `META-INF/resources` directory of your jar
- optionally include a `web-fragment.xml` in the `META-INF` directory of your jar
- place the jar in `WEB-INF/lib` directory of your war

You should then be able to reference your jsps in your context. For example if you have a jsp `META-INF/resources/test.jsp` you should be able reference this at the root of your context as `test.jsp`

Comment: Hi, I don't suppose you also know how to use the include directive for JSP files in a JAR? Absolute paths to /META-INF/tags doesn't seem to word and even an taglib directive throws errors..

Comment: And is there any way to be done with Servlet 2.5 or Tomcat 6?

Comment: Yeah, is it possible with Servlet 2.5 or Tomcat 5.5/6 ?

Comment: Is it standard? Do other containers such as Weblogic support this?

Comment: This question is about Tomcat 7.  My solution works for any servlet container implementing the Servlet 3.0 specification.  So Tomcat 7+ (but not Tomcat 6 and below). I've not used weblogic for a while but a quick google suggests support from 12c Release 1 (12.1.1).

Comment: @shousper You just reference it without the `/META-INF/resources` bit.  So if your jsp is `/META-INF/resources/somelib/somefile.jsp` you can use `<jsp:include page="/somelib/somefile.jsp" />`

Comment: I couldn't load `tiles-defs.xml`s this way. I'm getting the same issue of  `filenotfound` because of `ServletContext.getResource()`. where should I put `tiles-defs.xml`?

Comment: If this doesn't work straight away (e.g. 404s returned for the JSPs), this could be due to a restriction on the jar scanning in Tomcat.  In `conf/catalina.properties`, the `tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToScan` or `jarsToSkip` may be filtering this jar file out.

Answer (score 6):

As a workaround, I created a class that opens up a jar file, finds files matching a certain pattern, and extracts those files to a given location relative to the context path.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.jar.JarEntry;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

import org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher;
import org.springframework.web.context.ServletContextAware;

/**
 * Allows extraction of contents of a JAR file. All files matching a given Ant path pattern will be extracted into a
 * specified path.
 */
public class JarFileResourcesExtractor implements ServletContextAware {

    private String resourcePathPattern;
    private String jarFile;
    private String destination;
    private ServletContext servletContext;
    private AntPathMatcher pathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of the JarFileResourcesExtractor
     * 
     * @param resourcePathPattern
     *            The Ant style path pattern (supports wildcards) of the resources files to extract
     * @param jarFile
     *            The jar file (located inside WEB-INF/lib) to search for resources
     * @param destination
     *            Target folder of the extracted resources. Relative to the context.
     */
    private JarFileResourcesExtractor(String resourcePathPattern, String jarFile, String destination) {
        this.resourcePathPattern = resourcePathPattern;
        this.jarFile = jarFile;
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    /** 
     * Extracts the resource files found in the specified jar file into the destination path
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     *             If an IO error occurs when reading the jar file
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     *             If the jar file cannot be found
     */
    @PostConstruct
    public void extractFiles() throws IOException {
        try {
            String path = servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/lib/" + jarFile);
            JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(path);

            Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jarFile.entries();
            while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
                JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
                if (pathMatcher.match(resourcePathPattern, entry.getName())) {
                    String fileName = entry.getName().replaceFirst(".*\\/", "");
                    File destinationFolder = new File(servletContext.getRealPath(destination));
                    InputStream inputStream = jarFile.getInputStream(entry);
                    File materializedJsp = new File(destinationFolder, fileName);
                    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(materializedJsp);
                    copyAndClose(inputStream, outputStream);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Cannot find jar file in libs: " + jarFile);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IOException("IOException while moving resources.", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        this.servletContext = servletContext;
    }

    public static int IO_BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;

    private static void copyAndClose(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        try {
            byte[] b = new byte[IO_BUFFER_SIZE];
            int read;
            while ((read = in.read(b)) != -1) {
                out.write(b, 0, read);
            }
        } finally {
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

And then I configure it as a bean in my Spring XML:

```
<bean id="jspSupport" class="se.waxwing.util.JarFileResourcesExtractor">
   <constructor-arg index="0" value="jsp/*.jsp"/>
   <constructor-arg index="1" value="myJarFile-1.1.0.jar"/>
   <constructor-arg index="2" value="WEB-INF/classes/jsp"/>
</bean>
```

It's not an optimal solution to a really annoying problem. The question now becomes, will the guy who maintains this code come and [murder me while I sleep for doing this?](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CodeForTheMaintainer)

Comment: It ain't pretty, but I've seen much worse. One problem you might want to address, though: there's no functionality for *removing* a JSP when the jar containing it is removed.

Answer (score 4):

There is such workaround - you can precompile your JSPs into servlets. So you'll get .class files you can put into JAR and map in web.xml to some URLs.

Comment: Interesting. I am not sure how this will work with Tiles though (probably should have mentioned that we use that). I'm not sure what I would put in my tiles definition file.

Comment: Is it possible to expand on the subject?

Answer (score 4):

Struts 2 team added a plugin for embedded JSP. Maybe it may be used ad a base.

https://struts.apache.org/plugins/embedded-jsp/

Answer (score 1):

This is a follup to waxwing answer, which I've used becuase we used a server that could not do anything higher then servlet 2.5.

I added a method that removes the files added when the bean is destroyed.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.jar.JarEntry;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

import org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher;
import org.springframework.web.context.ServletContextAware;


import com.sap.tc.logging.Location;

/**
 * Allows extraction of contents of a JAR file. All files matching a given Ant path pattern will be extracted into a
 * specified path.
 * Copied from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013917/can-i-serve-jsps-from-inside-a-jar-in-lib-or-is-there-a-workaround
 */
public class JarFileResourcesExtractor implements ServletContextAware {

    private final transient Location logger = Location.getLocation(JarFileResourcesExtractor.class);

    private String resourcePathPattern;
    private String jarFile;
    private String destination;
    private ServletContext servletContext;
    private AntPathMatcher pathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();
    private List<File> listOfCopiedFiles = new ArrayList<File>();

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of the JarFileResourcesExtractor
     * 
     * @param resourcePathPattern
     *            The Ant style path pattern (supports wildcards) of the resources files to extract
     * @param jarFile
     *            The jar file (located inside WEB-INF/lib) to search for resources
     * @param destination
     *            Target folder of the extracted resources. Relative to the context.
     */
    public JarFileResourcesExtractor(String resourcePathPattern, String jarFile, String destination) {
        this.resourcePathPattern = resourcePathPattern;
        this.jarFile = jarFile;
        this.destination = destination;
    }


    @PreDestroy
    public void removeAddedFiles() throws IOException{
        logger.debugT("I removeAddedFiles()");
        for (File fileToRemove : listOfCopiedFiles) {
            if(fileToRemove.delete()){
                logger.debugT("Tagit bort filen " + fileToRemove.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }


    /** 
     * Extracts the resource files found in the specified jar file into the destination path
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     *             If an IO error occurs when reading the jar file
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     *             If the jar file cannot be found
     */
    @PostConstruct
    public void extractFiles() throws IOException {
        try {
            String path = servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/lib/" + jarFile);
            JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(path);

            Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jarFile.entries();
            while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
                JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
                if (pathMatcher.match(resourcePathPattern, entry.getName())) {
                    String fileName = entry.getName().replaceFirst(".*\\/", "");
                    File destinationFolder = new File(servletContext.getRealPath(destination));
                    InputStream inputStream = jarFile.getInputStream(entry);
                    File materializedJsp = new File(destinationFolder, fileName);
                    listOfCopiedFiles.add(materializedJsp);
                    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(materializedJsp);
                    copyAndClose(inputStream, outputStream);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Cannot find jar file in libs: " + jarFile);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IOException("IOException while moving resources.", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        this.servletContext = servletContext;
    }

    public static int IO_BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;

    private static void copyAndClose(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        try {
            byte[] b = new byte[IO_BUFFER_SIZE];
            int read;
            while ((read = in.read(b)) != -1) {
                out.write(b, 0, read);
            }
        } finally {
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I did change the constructor so I could use all java configuration:

```
@Bean 
public JarFileResourcesExtractor jspSupport(){
    final JarFileResourcesExtractor extractor = new JarFileResourcesExtractor("WEB-INF/pages/*.jsp","myJarFile-1.1.0.jar","WEB-INF/pages" );
    return extractor;
}
```

I hope someone this helps someone!