# Resolve spring MVC view from classpath

Tags: spring-mvc

I have some JSP views packaged inside a jar which I have on the Spring MVC web application's classpath. How do I set up a view resolver in the application's Spring XML file to resolve a view name to one of those classpath resources?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11063065/225448) on using JEE feature called web fragments to package JSPs in JAR files.

Answer (score 1):

The JAR file structure might matter. [§10.5 of Java Servlet 3.0 Spec](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf) says:

> ...For  example, for a Web application with the context path /catalog
>   in a Web container,  the index.html file at the base of the Web
>   application hierarchy or in a JAR file  inside WEB-INF/lib that
>   includes the index.html under META-INF/resources directory can be
>   served to satisfy a request from /catalog/index.html...

Maybe try serving your JSP in that manner. If it works then all you need is just a simple Spring InternalResourceViewResolver configured with the right prefix/suffix.