# Web application in other web application

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, servlet-2.5

I need to create a web application (servlets/jsp) as a JAR file which can be added in another web application in WEB-INF/lib folder. And it should be made available by making an entry in `web.xml` file.

Can this be done?

Comment: If you use Servlet 3.0 you can please check the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013917/can-i-serve-jsps-from-inside-a-jar-in-lib-or-is-there-a-workaround

Comment: @Karthikeyan, I use WebSphere Application Server 7 with Servlet 2.5.
This post don't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can do that:

1. Create Servlet classes / JSP files. Package them all in a .jar file. Don't include `web.xml` or any other files.
2. Import the jar in your *web application* `classpath`.
3. Configure Servlet classes and JSP files in your `web.xml` as below:

**For JSP:**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyJSPFile</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/path/to/jsp/MyJSP.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyJSPFile</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyJSP.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**For Servlet:**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>my.servlet.classpath.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
 
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyServlet.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```