# How to include JSP from jar lib

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a web-app with a lot of lib projects, which are common to another apps.
I'd like to put some JSP files in one of those libs and then make a `<jsp:include...` or `<%include...` But I'm not able to make it working.

Is there a way to achieve this?

If there is, which is better, to do a include directive (`@include file`..) or action (`<jsp:include page`...)?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'lib projects' ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I serve JSPs from inside a JAR in lib, or is there a workaround?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013917/can-i-serve-jsps-from-inside-a-jar-in-lib-or-is-there-a-workaround)

Comment: I already read that question and answers but not solving my problem.
By "Lib projects" I mean external JAR in the EAR Deployment Assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of only one way.

1. Keep the JSP in `/META-INF/resources` folder.
2. Create a 'lib' folder inside the WEB-INF folder in your WAR.
3. Place the JAR (containing the JSP in the `/META-INF/resources` folder) in the lib folder of the WAR.
4. In the main JSP where you want to include this external JSP residing in the JAR, use the following statement: `<jsp:include page="/myJSP.jsp" ></jsp:include>`. Note that the '/' is required in front of the jsp file name to make the container look for the JSP in an absolute path (and hence in the jar in the lib folder) rather than in the current path where the main JSP is lying.

This will surely work.

Comment: does this work in weblogic? should we do some configuration for it?

Comment: Give it a try. It should work in all JEE containers.

Comment: it seems it works for simple JSPs, but when including a JSP from a non JAR context (in webapps folder), there are problems in resolving them. Same thing works perfectly on Tomcat.... any suggestions?