# JSP file Include in from Jar file

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have two different project In first Project have all js,ftl java files and I included jsp file also in:

```
Webcontent/test.jsp
META-INF/resources/test.jsp
META-INF/test.jsp
```

When I exported this jar file in another project, I'm unable to call this jsp file.

Tried Following way:

```
<jsp:include page="/test.jsp"></jsp:include>
<jsp:include page="/test.jar!/resources/test.jsp"></jsp>
```

but it's still showing error while accessing this path in jsp.

Comment: Can you add the error message here?

Comment: Did u try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013917/can-i-serve-jsps-from-inside-a-jar-in-lib-or-is-there-a-workaround

Comment: Why do you need some jar in the web folder?