# Eclipse JSP in dependency project without Maven

Tags: eclipse, jsp, dependencies, tomcat7

I have the following setup:

Project A - A Dynamic Web project, which depends on project B.
Project B - A Dynamic Web project, that defines a Test.jsp file.

If I launch project B on the server, or move the Test.jsp to project A and launch project A on the server. it works just fine, and I can access the .../Test page'.

But when the Test.jsp remains in project B and I launch project A, although I do see the project-b.jar in the war file and the classes from project B does load, which means most of the process works ok, and only the jsps are not added...

How can I solve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013917/can-i-serve-jsps-from-inside-a-jar-in-lib-or-is-there-a-workaround

Comment: I've searched for quite some time, but didn't get to that question... Thanks, that question really solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Case anyone would get to this question, the solution described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013917/can-i-serve-jsps-from-inside-a-jar-in-lib-or-is-there-a-workaround) works well, though was not very clear at first:

In my project B, place your jsp files so:

```
src/main/webapp/META-INF/resources/${path-to-jsp}/file.jsp
```

In `src/main/webapp/META-INF/` create a web-fragment.xml with your variation of the following content:

```
<web-fragment
    metadata-complete="true"
    version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-fragment_3_0.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jspTest</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/${path-to-jsp}/file.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jspTest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-fragment>
```

and now if your buildpath is defined correctly, then clean-build both project B, and project A and run the server again... it works!