# How to support JSP file in two different locations with Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-boot

For some special reason, I have to support JSP files in two different locations.

Currently I wrote the following configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class JSPConfig {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/webpage/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        viewResolver.setOrder(1);
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver2() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/webpage/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        viewResolver.setOrder(2);
        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

But it does not work. The 1st `InternalResourceViewResolver` is for JSP file in my project, it works without any problem. The 2nd one is for JSP file in one 3rd party jar with the following path `{jarfilename}\org\apache\jsp\webpage\modules\gen`. And the path for 3rd party jar file in final war file is `{warfilename}\WEB-INF\lib\`. I use the JSP file as `modules/gen/{some_jsp_name_without_suffix}` in one controller. Unfortunately the JSP file in the 3rd can not be located.

Through debugging step by step, I noticed that the reason is that it never tries to locate and match the 2nd `InternalResourceViewResolver` under current configuration. It tries to match the 1st view resolver, failed. It tries to match some `.ftl` view resolver, failed.

Could any one give me a hand? Does Spring boot support locating JSP files under two different paths?

Thanks very much.

Comment: No it doesn't. And that has nothing to do with Spring Boot but how the `UrlViewResovler` works internally.

Comment: @M.Deinum you mean there is no way to work around?

Comment: @Jiang Have you looked at the answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013917/can-i-serve-jsps-from-inside-a-jar-in-lib-or-is-there-a-workaround)

Comment: You could extend the `InternalResourceViewResolver` and check if the actual resolved URL would exist. But this could be very bad for performance.